# doubled letter when I using \bm

Tags: bm

When I using the `\bm` package, all the letters are overprinting like below.

I could not find the problem.

[image]

Comment: Provide an example that compiles, please.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: That is bm's last resort "poor man's bold" which it does if there are no bold fonts available. What font are you using? Is there a bold font?

Answer (score 5):

This document reproduces your issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\hat{\bm{R}}$

\end{document}
```

You essentially cannot use `bm` with `mathptmx`.

Solution: use `newtx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\hat{\bm{R}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
1. I don't use \usepackage{mathptmx}. so I am not sure it is the reason.
2. when I add \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
An error appear: Option clash for package textcomp. \DeclareRobustCommand
Too many math alphabets used in version normal. \begin{document}

Answer (score 0):

In the template, there are three fonts could be choose:

1.`times' : Times font with math support.

2.`fourier': Utopia Font with Fourier Math font (Font has to be installed) It's a free font.

3.`customfont': Use`customfont' option in the document class and load the package in the preamble.tex

4. default or leave empty: `Latin Modern' font will be loaded.
   If I use "times" the problem appears,

but If I use "fourier" and "Latin Modern" the problem solved. Maybe because I don't have the bold fonts for "times" and I don't know which bold fonts corresponding to "times" and how to add it.