# Math symbols (bm) appear duplicate/on top of themselves

Tags: math-mode, bm

In a recent document I'm working on, when using certain math symbols they are duplicated over themselves:

[image]

This happens exclusively when I use `\bm{}`. It happens in inline math, equations, and aligns. Has anyone else seen this happen?

Here are the relevant packages I'm using

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
```

And also the documentclass from [here](http://www.aes.org/journal/authors/guidelines/).

```
\documentclass{aes2e}
```

EDIT: Here is a MWE

```
\begin{equation}
    \text{bm: }\bm{x}\quad\text{boldsymbol: } \boldsymbol{x}\quad\text{regular:} x
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Edit 2: Thanks to everyone for your help, this is indeed a duplicate question. After searching through the journal of interest it appears that nobody uses `\bm` or even `\boldsymbol`, but instead they use `\mathbf`. This leaves me with a bit of a problem for bold symbols as the duplication still happens, even with `\pmb`. My current solution is from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/is-there-any-way-other-than-pmb-to-produce-bold-greek-letters-when-mathptmx-is) which suggests switching to CM for greek symbols, but it looks less bold than Times.

Comment: Try using `\boldsymbol{x}` instead.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In general you should provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` and reproduces your issue. In this case something like `\documentclass{aes2e}\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}\usepackage{bm}\begin{document}$\bm{x}$\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried `\boldsymbol` and it appears to give the exact same result.

Comment: Are you using a special font package? Please advise.

Comment: There is a lot of specification in the `.cls` file but I'm not sure what I should be looking for. It was written 8 years ago and is 1773 lines long!

Comment: potential duplicate: [doubled letter when I using \bm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424894/579)

Comment: I have tried following the suggestion from that thread but when replacing `mathptmx` with `newtxtext,newtxmath` in the `.cls` file I receive the following error: `! Improper at size (0.0pt), replaced by 10pt.<to be read again>relax \end{align}`

Comment: @loudnoises You probably have to upgrade your TeX system.